# How can I choose the empty variable to create before using for in R

Tags: r, for-loop

are many days that I have a doubt about the empty variable that I have to create before a `for` loop.

I explain my problem:

I created a `for` that makes me a url. It works correctly (I don't write the code here, because it links with other variables).

The result is a table of one column and six rows (for easely I put here a list of urls).

```
url_web<-(c("https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roma",
            "https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milano",
            "https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoli",
            "https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torino",
            "https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palermo",
            "https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venezia"))
```

My focus is to store, in this case, the pages title.

To do this I wrote this code.

```
   dis_1<- data.frame()
for (i in url_web) {
  url_scrap <- i
  url_scrap <- read_html(url_scrap)
  dis <- html_nodes(url_scrap, ".firstHeading")%>% html_text()
  print(distanza_dal)
  dis_1<- rbind(dis_1,dis)
}
```

The code works correclty but I can't to store the datas.

R gives me this error.

```
    Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(1L, NA)) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(1L, NA, NA)) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
3: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(1L, NA, NA, NA)) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
4: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(1L, NA, NA, NA, NA)) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
5: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Somebody, kindly, could explain me where is my mistake and a general rules that I have to follow to avoid future errors as this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be a working solution for you, if you just want the page title:

```
#as a general matter you should declare which packages you are using

library(rvest)
library(xml2)

dis_1 <- data.frame()

#you need to run through all elements of your vector one at a time
for (i in 1:length(url_web)) {
       #read in the HTML
      url_scrap <- read_html(url_web[i])
        #extract the relevant chunks
      dis <- html_nodes(url_scrap, ".firstHeading") %>% 
        html_text()
        #make a new data frame with the title info you were looking for
      dis2 <- data.frame(page_title = dis)
        #join it to the main data frame
      dis_1 <- rbind(dis_1,dis2)
    }
```

Returned values:

```
  page_title
1       Roma
2     Milano
3     Napoli
4     Torino
5    Palermo
6    Venezia
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that the character strings you are reading are converted to `factor` which causes the warnings.

See this simplified version of your question:

```
dis_1 <- data.frame()
dis_1 <- rbind(dis_1, "a")
dis_1 <- rbind(dis_1, "b")
```

This generates a warning. To circumvent this use `stringsAsFactors = F` inside `rbind` and inside `data.frame`:

```
dis_1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F)
dis_1 <- rbind(dis_1, "a", stringsAsFactors = F)
dis_1 <- rbind(dis_1, "b", stringsAsFactors = F)
```